# Excel: how to pick the same MONTH column in a vlookup()-match() combo?

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I am using a `vlookup()` in order to correspond values from one table to another. The real data are much more and spread over multiple sheets, not necessarily with in alike template; which is why I need to use `match` in combination.

In my example shown below, I would like to NOT USE the `$A$7:$E$7` cells, because that would mean that I need to add an extra piece of information in the main sheet which needs to follow a template.

To be more explicit, the formula says to vlookup the values in column G within the table of A2:E5 cells and take the value from the corresponding columns which matches with the same month. Do you have any ideas? (VBA is not within the scope). Thanks in advance ^_^

[image]

Comment: What about `Match(Month(H$2),Month($A$2:$E$2),FALSE)` with array entry. What is your excel version?

Comment: Nope, this does not work. I have a mac version of escel (16.16.27). But I also tried it in google sheets. :-(